# Criar menu de navegacao jquery metodo load

Tags: php, jquery, html

Estou com algumas dificuldades em criar um menu em que as paginas são carregadas dentro  de uma `div`.

O que acontece é que estou criando uma aplicação seguindo o padrão MVC, e eu faço os tratamentos das URLs para assim os redirecionar, para cada controller, não sei o que se passa quando ele carrega a página ele não abre especificamente na `div` onde predefini.

Codigo jQuery:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.ler').click(function () {
        jQuery('#open').load('corpo.php', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
})
```

Codigo HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="<?php URL?>dashboard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ler"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Categorias</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php URL?>noticia" class="ler"><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Noticias</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php URL?>galeria" class="ler"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Galeria</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php URL?>comentarios" class="ler"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Comentarios</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php URL?>informacoes" class="ler"><i class="fa fa-font"></i> Informacoes</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></i> Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Enviar Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gerir Usuarios</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

E a `div` onde as páginas serão carregadas:

```
<!-- /#navegacao -->
<div id="open"></div>
<!-- /#navegacao //Fim -->
```

Comment: Sam você está a usar a função dentro do :load() de maneira errada. O que pretende com o `.preventDefault()`? Essa função é a função que corre quando o ajax tem sucesso, e o parâmetro `e` (que costuma ser chamado "resposnse") é a resposta, provavelmente HTML...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muito provavelmente você está tendo o problema que descreveu pelo fato de você ter invocado um método de *evento* através de um argumento de resposta, o qual é sempre uma string.

Veja funcionando [no Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xa5sY/)

O argumento *event* deve ser definido num manipulador de evento. No seu caso, um evento de clique, logo, ele é argumento do primeiro *callback*.

O segundo *callback* é a resposta do servidor, que é uma string (teste com **typeof**), logo, o método [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) não existe.

Aliás, quando usando jQuery.load(), informar um callback quase sempre é útil apenas durante o desenvolvimento, unicamente para se ter acesso ao objeto XHR e, de repente, dele extrair o HTTP Response Code (200, 301, 404...) e o significado dele (OK, Moved, Not Found...).

Comment: Muito obrigado, seja você quem for. <_<

Comment: Obrigado Consegui ALterar e funciona correctamente

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como resolvido e, de repente, desfazer o que outros fizeram sem motivo.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de ler e pesquisar aqui no forum, encontrei uma solução

function abreURL(url,metodo,onde){
   if(metodo=='POST'){
      // metodo post
       $.post(url, function(data) {
      // página do carregador (loading)
       $("#carregador").show();
       $( "#"+onde).load(url);
      });
   }
   else if(metodo=='GET'){
      // metodo get
      $.get(url, function(data) {
     // página do carregador (loading)
      $("#carregador").show();
     $( "#"+onde).load(url);
    });
  }
}

E No html e so chamar a funcao no metodo onclick()

views/categoria/index.php','GET','conteodo');" href="#" >